# Run-time error 1004 when running a sorting module in a private sub

Tags: excel, vba

I will try to make this as detailed as possible.

**Summarize the problem**

I am trying to create a module that multi-level sorts Active Sheet's Table. I created that. Whenever I call it from the Macros Tab, it works perfectly.

The problem comes whenever I try to call that module in a Private Sub. When I do it, I get a ***Run-time Error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed***.

**Describe what you've tried**

I have pretty much searched around everywhere and I finally stumbled upon that code that uses the ActiveSheet aspect so that whenever I duplicate this sheet, it doesn't cause any issues with breaking the automation.

**Show some code**

Here is the code of the module:

```
Sub Sort1()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[ÐÑÏÌÇÈÅÕÔÇÓ]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[ÇÌ/ÍÉÁ ÅÊÄÏÓÇÓ]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

So this is the Private Sub I have that I am trying to call the macro/module from and not have it crash:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Range("B2") = "¸ëåã÷ïò Ìçôñþïõ Ðáãßùí" Then
    Columns("AC:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("C:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("M:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("AD:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Áí ðñïóôåèïýí íÝåò äáðÜíåò êáé ðáñáäïôÝá ôïõò, ôï BD ðñÝðåé íá áëëÜîåé êáé íá ãßíåé ç ôåëåõôáßá óôÞëç
    Call Module2.Sort2
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "¸ëåã÷ïò Âéâëßïõ Åîüäùí" And Range("B1") = "B- ÁðëïãñáöéêÜ" Then
    Columns("C:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("AA:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("M:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("AB:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Áí ðñïóôåèïýí íÝåò äáðÜíåò êáé ðáñáäïôÝá ôïõò, ôï BD ðñÝðåé íá áëëÜîåé êáé íá ãßíåé ç ôåëåõôáßá óôÞëç
    Call Module2.Sort2
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "¸ëåã÷ïò ÊáñôÝëáò" And Range("B1") = "Ã- ÄéðëïãñáöéêÜ" Then
    Columns("D:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("AB:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("N:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("L:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("Q:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("R:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("AC:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Áí ðñïóôåèïýí íÝåò äáðÜíåò êáé ðáñáäïôÝá ôïõò, ôï BD ðñÝðåé íá áëëÜîåé êáé íá ãßíåé ç ôåëåõôáßá óôÞëç
    Call Module1.Sort1
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "¸ëåã÷ïò Extrait" Then
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("N:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("U:U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("J:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("R:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("V:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Áí ðñïóôåèïýí íÝåò äáðÜíåò êáé ðáñáäïôÝá ôïõò, ôï BD ðñÝðåé íá áëëÜîåé êáé íá ãßíåé ç ôåëåõôáßá óôÞëç
    Call Module2.Sort2
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "¸ëåã÷ïò Åëëåßøåùí Ôéìïëïãßùí" Then
    Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("AD:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("N:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Call Module1.Sort1
 Else 'Áí ðñïóôåèïýí íÝåò äáðÜíåò êáé ðáñáäïôÝá ôïõò, èá ðñÝðåé íá ìðïõí ôá Columns åäþ.
    Columns("C:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("S:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns1
    Columns("Z:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns1
    Columns("AB:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns1
    Columns("AA:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns2
    Columns("AD:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns3
    Columns("X:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns4
    Columns("V:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns5
    Columns("W:W").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns6
    Columns("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns7
    Columns("U:U").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns8
    Columns("AE:AG").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns9
    Columns("AH:AI").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns10
    Columns("AJ:AJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns11
    Columns("AK:AK").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns12
    Columns("AL:AL").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns13
    Columns("AM:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns14
    Columns("AO:AO").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns15
    Columns("AP:AQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns16
    Columns("AR:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns17
    Columns("AS:AS").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns18
    Columns("AT:AU").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns19
    Columns("AV:AV").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns20
    Columns("AW:BB").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns21
    Columns("BC:BD").EntireColumn.Hidden = hideColumns22
    Call Module3.Sort3
 End If
End Sub
```

Module1,Module2, Module3 are just different variation of the above module.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Solution found by @BigBen. Here is the changed code:

```
Sub Sort1()
' Áõôü ôï module êÜíåé sort ðñþôá áíÜ ðñïìçèåõôÞ êáé ìåôÜ áíÜ çìåñïìçíßá
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[ÐÑÏÌÇÈÅÕÔÇÓ]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[ÇÌ/ÍÉÁ ÅÊÄÏÓÇÓ]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen The code goes on for a forever loop so whenever I click "Debug", excel closes. I don't know if there is another way to find out.

FYI The private sub itself runs perfectly when I don't call the module and the module itself runs perfectly by itself if I don't call it from the Sub but simply run it once.

Comment: Do you have a `Select` anywhere in `Sort1`, `Sort2`, or `Sort3`? You probably should disable events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`); it sounds like the event is firing in an infinite loop.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much, I am updating the code as we speak :)

Comment: It's probably better to control events from within the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event code. Also, make sure to have an error handler so that `Application.EnableEvents = True` is always executed, regardless of an error.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for the insight, I will see what I can do for that :)